# lotus notes use colors for column values for a categorized column

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

The column ( i checked the `Use value as color` and it is categorized by this column) formula is:

```
@If(txt_radiobutton = "Foaie de livrare"; text_livratfl;text_tehnicianrs)
```

the 2 fields: `text_livratfl` and `text_tehnicianrs`, let say, can take one of this 4 values: A , B, C or D.

Is it possible to display A in red, B in blue , and so on ... every value in different color?

I've declared all the 'colors' below ( in the column formula )

```
red := 255:0:0;
blue := 0:0:255;
yellow := 255:255:0;
pink := 255:193:253;
white := 255:255:255;
black := 1:1:1;
apricot := 255:155:133;
```

but I don't know how to manage the `@if` formula, considering the fact that the column value is displaying one of two values.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have two columns: 1 for the color, and one for the category.

First you have the color- column. It is hidden and contains the following formula:

```
red := 255:0:0;
blue := 0:0:255;
yellow := 255:255:0;
pink := 255:193:253;
white := 255:255:255;
black := 1:1:1;
apricot := 255:155:133;

_textValue := @If(txt_radiobutton = "Foaie de livrare"; 
              text_livratfl;text_tehnicianrs);
@If( _textValue = "A"; red;
     _textValue = "B"; blue; 
     _textValue = "C"; yellow;
     black );
```

Your Category- Column stays the same as it is at the moment.

Unfortunately color columns do not work for categories, but only for flat columns, so probably what you want will not be possible at all.

If you want only one column to be colored, then you enter another color column right after that column and give it the formula `-1 : -1 : -1`

Comment: Just to expand a bit: in a categorized column, a document with a _textValue of "A":"B" would appear in both the "A" category and the "B" category, and for that document, the column colour would have to be *both* red and blue according to any colour column formula you could possibly write. (Note, though, that it is possible, even trivial, to write a formula that will work in the browser, since you can tie the colour value and the text value together as a single column value, at the expense of making RestricToCategory weird. You can use an agent (a WQO or standalone) to get around that.)

Comment: Great explanation. In web you think about something like `<font color="red">Categoryvalue</font>`?